# Is there any way to see whole code of subclass (from upper hierarchy) combined in one view

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, refactoring, class-hierarchy

If a class has 5 layers of hierarchy, is there a way or a tool to combine all the code from the hierarchy into one class (using only method definition from deepest layer)?

While doing API versioning we have a single codebase and we're using inheritance to change logic (only if needed) in different versions while also reusing code from older versions. 
What you get after 20 versions is that one class can have hierarchy with 20 layers. Oldest 10 versions are deprecated (not visible to public) but the code is still there to be reused by newer versions.

What we want to do now is to take those 10 oldest versions and combine them into one (latest of the deprecated versions). That way we will have less chaos in the codebase. One way of doing that is going through 10 versions and combining methods yourself into one class, but is there a way of doing that programatically?

Thanks

Comment: There's no native feature to do what you want. Any solution would probably be pretty complex. It will probably be easier, less error prone and much faster to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by applying [Push Down Method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/pushDownMethod.html) iteratively:

> Behavior on a superclass is relevant only for some of its subclasses.
>
> Move it to those subclasses.

Not advertising anything but this kind of refactoring can be done using IDE. For example, PhpStorm can help you with this providing [push members down](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/pull-members-up.html) functionality.